# bought .eth domains in 2017, still Controller, no longer Registrant

Tags: ens, registrars

Back in November 2017 I bought 4 or 5 .eth domains.  They show up on my ENS account as my wallet being the Controller but not the Registrant.

However, when I go into details, it shows there's neither a Registrant or Controller address associated with the domain.

When I go to Register them, the message I get is that they're already registered.

The Resolver message is that I'm using an outdated version of the public resolver, but I'm unable to click Migrate, or to Set the Resolver.

How do I re-claim/re-register these?

Comment: Maybe someone else registered them already? Please check the ENS Discord, forum, or GIthub https://ens.domains/ and post an answer here when you find out.